# AttributeError: Can't set attribute - How can I fix it?

Tags: python, ponyorm

I am working on developing tests with pytest, but I am encountering the *AttributeError: can't set attribute*.

This is the model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Entity):
   _table_ = 'users'
   email = Required(str, unique=True)
   username = Required(str, unique=True)
   password_hash = Optional(str)
   pretax_income = Optional(Decimal, default=110000)
   tax_rate = Optional(Decimal, default=0.1)

   @property
   @db_session
   def monthly_income(self):
      return round(self.pretax_income/12, 2)

   @property
   @db_session
   def post_tax_income(self):
      return round(self.pretax_income - (self.pretax_income * self.tax_rate), 2)

  @property
  @db_session
  def post_tax_income_monthly(self):
      return round(self.post_tax_income / 12, 2)
```

And this is where I am doing the tests, from which the first 2 work fine. The last one testing the monthly post tax income gets the error about setting the attribute.

```
class TestCalculator:

@db_session
def test_calc_monthly_income(self):
    user = User.get(email='test@test.com')
    user.pretax_income = 12000
    assert user.monthly_income == Decimal('1000')
    user.pretax_income = 48000
    assert user.monthly_income== Decimal('4000')

@db_session
def test_calc_post_tax_income(self):
    user = User.get(email='test@test.com')
    user.pretax_income = 120000
    user.tax_rate = 0.1
    assert user.post_tax_income == 108000
    user.pretax_income = 90000
    user.tax_rate = 0.2
    assert user.post_tax_income == 72000

@db_session
def test_calc_post_tax_income_monthly(self):
    user = User.get(email='test@test.com')
    user.post_tax_income = 36000
    assert user.post_tax_income_monthly == Decimal('3000')
    user.post_tax_income = 60000
    assert user.post_tax_income_monthly == Decimal('5000')
```

Update: I tried to add a setter in this way. Clearly, I am doing it wrong.

```
   @post_tax_income.setter
@db_session
def set_post_tax_income(self):
    self.post_tax_income = post_tax_income
```

Comment: You've defined `post_tax_income` as a property with a getter and no setter. So you can only get it, not set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property
@db_session
def post_tax_income(self):
  return round(self.pretax_income - (self.pretax_income * self.tax_rate), 2)
```

this defines only a getter. It allows you fetch the value but you can't do this:

```
user.post_tax_income = 36000
```

This requires a setter to also be defined:

```
@post_tax_income.setter
def set_post_tax_income(self):
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I get your point. I added the below, but still unsure where the problem lies. This is the first time I use a setter.

Comment: '''@post_tax_income.setter
    @db_session
    def set_post_tax_income(self):
        self.post_tax_income = post_tax_income

Comment: That depends on your program. What would setting `post_tax_income` even mean? Since `post_tax_income` seems to be a computed attribute, does it even make sense to set it? Maybe you need to re-evaluate how the test has been written

Comment: Right, it's a computed attribute.

Comment: Then why are you trying to set it in the test? What is that supposed to achieve? If the intention is to test the `post_tax_income_monthly` method, then why aren't you doing that in the same test where, `post_tax_income` is tested? i.e if post_tax_income is verified, then you verify the `post_tax_income_monthly` method as well. Then you wouldn't need to know the `post_tax_income` beforehand

Comment: lol, I dont know. I guess I was used to testing each calculation separately. Thank you, it works now. You're a genius.